# Android Fragment SetTitle() is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

setTitle(menuItem.getTitle()) is not working whenever a fragment is called it is not setting up.Whenever I tried to change or jump from one fragment to another at that time action bar is set with app name only.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar mToolBar;
    NavigationView mNavigationView;
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerView,new HomeFragment()).commit();
        }

        mToolBar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mNavigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigationDrawer);


        mActionBarDrawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();

        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);

        setupDrawerContent(mNavigationView);
    }

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle(){

        return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,mToolBar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close);
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView mNavigationView){
        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem){


        Fragment fragment = null;

        Class fragmentClass;


        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){


            case R.id.nav_home:
                fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
                break;

            case R.id.nav_rate_card:
                fragmentClass = RateCardFragment.class;
                break;

            case R.id.nav_orders:
                fragmentClass = OrderFragment.class;
                break;

            case R.id.nav_setting:
                fragmentClass = SettingFragment.class;
                break;

            case R.id.nav_about_us:
                fragmentClass = AboutUsFragment.class;
                break;

            default:
                fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;

        }

        try{
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerView,fragment).commit();


        // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
        //menuItem.setChecked(true);
        // Set action bar title
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }

        if (mActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
       mActionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do u want to show fragment name when u select specific fragment?

Comment: Try this not sure it'll work. set The tool bar title in the switch case i.e. here switch (menuItem.getItemId()){}

Comment: I had used switch case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getSupportActionBar().setTitle()` and try.

Answer (score 0):

take one textview in your toolbar.xml and access it.like this

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbarf);
    toolbartitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titletool);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbartitle.setText("Hindi_Dialouges");
```

Comment: can you send me your toolbar.xml file